# How to understand the relationship between tail recursion and for loop in DFS

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement the "subset" algorithm using DFS. And I found both the following two programs work:

```
def DFS(nums, begin, path, res):
    res.append(path[:])

    for i in range(begin, len(nums)):
        path.append(nums[i])
        DFS(nums, i + 1, path, res)
        path.pop()


def DFS_2(nums, begin, path, res):
    if begin == len(nums):
        res.append(path[:])
        return

    path.append(nums[begin])
    DFS_2(nums, begin + 1, path, res) #choose the current element
    path.pop()
    DFS_2(nums, begin + 1, path, res) #not choose the current element
```

test code is:

```
nums = [i for i in range(1, 4)]
res = []
path = []

DFS_2(nums, 0, path, res)
print(res)

res2 = []
DFS(nums, 0, path, res2)
print(res2)
```

Output is:

DFS_2:  `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1], [2, 3], [2], [3], []]`

DFS:    `[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]`

I can understand `DFS_2`, since in each recursion, I have two choices - choose the current element or not choose the current element. But I'm having difficulty understanding function `DFS`. How to understand the `for` loop in that function `DFS`? My guess is that there is tail recursion in function `DFS_2`, which is the reason why function `DFS` and `DFS_2` are equivalent to each other, but I'm not sure about the details.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: how can we help you without knowing what you'll be actually having in those variables (nums, begin, path, res)?

Comment: test code and output added

Comment: My suggestion is that you get one peace of paper, and draw what is going on. All will be much more clear then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, functions **DFS** and **DFS_2** are almost equivalent to each other. Yes, you have two choices in function **DFS_2** and it's truly easy to see, but also there are same two choices in function **DFS**. When program appends element in *PATH* list, then it's doing recursion for that *PATH*, but when that **branch** of recursion is over, same element is erased from path and then it's starting same kind of recursion as it was before, but without that element in *PATH* list.

If you print *PATH* list after every append in **DFS** function, output will be :

('Path After Append : ', [1])

('Path After Append : ', [1, 2])

('Path After Append : ', [1, 2, 3])

('Path After Append : ', [1, 3])

('Path After Append : ', [2])

('Path After Append : ', [2, 3])

('Path After Append : ', [3])

Let's see, recursion started with first element and all the possible permutations were made. After that, same recursion was made but without first element in it and so on, same thing was done for all elements in list. To sum up, every *recursion of **i** th* element in list sees all the elements after itself and does every possible permutations. At the beginning first element is put in the list, then goes recursion and second is put, then third, then recursion dives up, erases third element, then second one and adds third again but there is no second element there any more. Then second element is erased and all permutations are done for first one. Same thing happens for all of them, but as I said, every *recursion of **i** th* element in list sees all the elements after itself only.

Comment: That is exactly the "high-level" understanding I needed. Really appreciated!